# How to set a decimal value up to 8 decimal places in php

Tags: php, math

I want to show amount of bitcoins up to 8 decimal points. I have stored the value in Satoshi but when I try to convert the satoshi to BTC by dividing the satoshi value with 100000000 I am getting invalid result. here is my code.

```
            $res = 3535/100000000;
            echo $res;
```

the output of the above code is 3.535E-5 isntead 0.00003535.
please tell me the proper solution.

Comment: `number_format` is probably what your are searching for

Comment: No its not duplicate question. Problem to show a number up to 8 places. code is working up to 7 places when I try to increase one more decimal place it gives wrong output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo number_format(3535/100000000, 8);
```

Where 8 is the count of 0's. For example for 3535/1000000000 you need to write

```
echo number_format(3535.0/1000000000, 9);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working.... :)

Comment: If this is working, then it is a duplicate question after all ;-)